# Draw.io autosize by keeping width fixed, and expanding height if needed

Tags: draw.io

Is there a way in draw.io, to autosize a text container, keeping it's `width` fixed, and telling `draw.io` to only adjust the height if neccessary?

I tried out almost all options in the properties of the text box, but when I apply the autosize, it always overwrites my set width and height, by making the width larger, and the height smaller.

I am putting these texts inside a `swimlane`, and what I would like to achieve is, either:

1. when I add text to these text rectangles, the `rectangle` and the `swimlane` should expand automatically, but only vertically, ie, only the height of it should change (this would be the best for me, so that it is automatic)
2. if the automatic solution is not achievable, I would be happy with something like manually pressing the autosize button, and `draw.io` should keep my width fixed, and change the size of the height only.

Comment: Interestingly, I think that's the way it is now. And I want to be auto-size the width lol.

Comment: A relevant need, I think. Adding links: Has been asked over at webapps too.
( https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73516/how-to-resize-a-draw-io-text-box-automatically-to-fit-the-text#comment61694_73523 )

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find any documentation anywhere. But I notice that the behaviour of auto wrap is different depending on the object type that you choose. For example,

[image]

The above one is a "Rectangle". it won't resize the width when auto-sizing. The bottom one is a "UML/Object". It will resize both the width and height.

Answer (score 0):

I think these are the two settings you want to toggle on for the object to make it:

- Lock the width
- Expand in the height

[image: Autosize | Fixed width]

I'll be honest; I, personally, would like to make it expand downwards always, but it seems like that isn't possible

Comment: Doesn't work for text on the arrows. I mean the text appearing when double clicking the arrow and put there.